# How to add a subclass as a subview so that background of subview is set in front of superview

Tags: objective-c, ios, subview

I got 2 classes

```
@interface PlayScene : UIView
```

and

```
@interface GameOverMenu : PlayScene <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

in PlayScene I create an instance of GameOverMenu

```
GameOverMenu* gorm = [[GameOverMenu alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
gorm.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self addSubview:gorm];
```

But background is set not for subview but for superview, I mean background doesn't hide elements of PlayScene view so that buttons and some drawing remain in front of the background

If the problem is still not clear, I want to make my subview stand in front of superview with black(for example) background, covering the whole screen in front of superview.
As if subview class was inherited just from UIView and not from PlayScene

Comment: Have you tried -bringSubViewToFront?

Comment: I did, it doesn't bring my subview in front of superview (PlayScene)

Comment: What exactly makes you say that your subview is behind the superview??

Comment: totally it doesn't appear behind superview, but I seems that the problem is that background is set for superview, not for the real subview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any of the below methods :

- `insertSubview: atIndex:`
- `insertSubview: aboveSubview:`
- `bringSubviewToFront:`

**EDIT**

If you are trying to create an instance of `GameOverMenu` which is subclass of `PlayScene` and then add this instance as subview on the view of `PlayScene`, then probably you can try creating an instance each of `PlayScene` and `GameOverMenu` and adding these two as subview to a third view.. maybe ViewControllers view or maybe just a view.. based on your requirement...

Comment: Well I need to bring subview in front of superview, but all of this, if I understand it right, is working only for subviews. I write smth like [self insertSubview:gorm atIndex:0]; and it doesn't work right for me.

Comment: i am not sure if I got your question right, but can this help ? `[self insertSubview:gorm atIndex:[[self subviews] count]]`

Comment: that works for subviews, and I need to put my subview in front of superview if it is possible

Comment: Typically I've found subviews to be stacked in front of superviews and I've successfully rearranged the order using bringSubviewToFront, whether its small UIViews in a screen or full screen UIViews of ViewControllers. Try it and if it doesn't work, give some more info for clues.

Comment: I create CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520) that covers all the screen, when I the super class of GameOverMenu was UIView, subviews stacked in front of superview, but now they are not on some reason

Comment: well yes it appear it front of superview, but background is still made behind super view

Comment: Something tells me the problem is cuz, you are trying to create an instance of `GameOverMenu` which is subclass of `PlayScene` and then add this instance as subview on the view of `PlayScene`... is this right.. why am i getting confused... :(  Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: yes it is, how else I can add subview so that in that subview I could use properties of PlayScene class? only with the help of another view controller?

Comment: how about creating an instance each of PlayScene and GameOverMenu and adding these two as subview to a third view.. maybe ViewControllers view or maybe just a view.. based on your requirement... Tried this ?

Comment: I tried it just now, I have made a new UIView class,, PlayScene and GameOverMenu inherit it. It seems that GameOverMenu doesn't live without PlayScene added as a subclass, 'cause at first I remove instance of PlayScene from superview and than call superclass method, which should add an instance of GameOverMenu as a subview. But nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: Done it now, just used new UIView class as a superclass for both PlayScene and GameOverMenu and moved all properties to it. Thanks mate! Could you arrange it as an answer so that I could mark it accepted